# failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error) webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, morris.js

I am calling a web method in a web page to bind data to morris charts, but facing issues resource not found. The error is:

> failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error)

I had also put break point to check if web method is called, but debugger never hits that point.

```
function Graph() {
        var data = "";
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/MainMenuB.aspx/ProcessRequestNew") %>',
            dataType: 'json',                
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},

            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                data = response;
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                debugger;
                alert(error);
            }
        });

        debugger;
        return data;
    }
```

webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string ProcessRequestNew()

{
    List<GraphData> dataList = new List<GraphData>();

    SqlConnection connM = new SqlConnection(connstr);

    string chartName = "line";
    string data = string.Empty;

    GraphData graphData = null;        

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chartName))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        if (connM.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connM.Open();
        }
        cmd.Connection = connM;
        cmd.CommandText = "SPR_FE_Dashboard";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", "NewB");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SP_Flag", "INQ");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GraphData details = new GraphData();
            graphData.label = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["WK"].ToString());
            graphData.value = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Quantity"].ToString());               
            dataList.Add(details);
        }
    }


    data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataList);
    return data;


}
```

Comment: If you never hit the first line then some module may be failing before your handler is invoked.

Comment: None of module is failing..

Comment: Then if you have no logs I suggest that you set the VS to break on all the CLR exceptions (Ctrl-Alt-E) and check what is throwing.

Comment: Since this is an Internal **server** error, your server is tried to be called, but is not responding properly. In the browser's debugger tool, expand the Response to identify the Exception property (you may need to go recursive) which will hint what's actually misbehaving.